# Prevent Android from sleeping while the Flashplayer is running

Tags: android, flash

I've written a videoplayer for Android based on Flash (10.2) which plays videostreams. In some cases (*), the player begins to buffer for quite some time.

Now, while the player is acually playing the stream, Flash (somehow) signals the OS to prevent entering the sleep-mode. But while buffering, this is not the case and the phone will eventually enter sleep mode before the stream has restarted. So the user has to unlock the phone again - not very convenient.

**Is there a way to set a signal with Flash/AS3 to prevent the Andoid-phone to go into sleep mode?**

(*) mostly over the mobile network when the network access performes a handover between 3G and 2G or vice versa

Comment: use wakelocks.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
// no dimming
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
```

in your mxml or as file.

Comment: then i misunderstood this - thought the videoplayer was some kind of app, not running in the browser.